# Git tag - why is this happening now?

Tags: git

My tags have stopped updating, pretty sure I'm not doing anything different from before. Anybody know how to resolve this?

```
$ git tag
v1.0.2
v1.0.3
v1.0.4
v1.0.5
v1.0.6
v1.0.7
v1.0.8
v1.0.9

$ git tag v1.1.0

$ git push --tags
 * [new tag]         v1.1.0 -> v1.1.0
```

What I expect is

```
* [new tag]         v1.0.9 -> v1.1.0
```

**Note** `git push origin v1.1.0` does the same thing

Comment: Why did you expect what you expected? The output of the command said "I pushed the local tag v1.1.0 which became the remote tag v1.1.0".

Comment: I need it to do what it did previously which was to update  v1.0.9 -> v1.1.0. Composer won't update the package

Comment: So you removed the `v1.0.9` tag? Because it sounds to me like you don't really understand how git tags work.

Comment: The tags are readonly pointers to commits. The output you get is correct, the one you expect is not how tags work. The output of `[new tag]         v1.1.0 -> v1.1.0` tell the tag `v1.1.0` (you created with `git tag v1.1.0`) is not present on the remote (`[new tag]`) and it was sent to the remote (`-> v1.1.0`).

Comment: If you are troubleshooting a Composer issue you better check the restrictions you put in `composer.json`.

Comment: It's not composer I have it as "1.*", must be something else then

Comment: Put `-vvv` in the `composer`'s command line to be sure it's not Composer's fault. Many times Composer is the troublemaker.

Comment: Resolved it. git push --tags doesn't also push my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything to resolve because nothing looks wrong.

When you create a tag, in reality all you're doing is creating a label, a post-it note, putting a name on this label, and attaches it to a specific commit.

```
git tag v1.1.0
```

does this, and since you didn't specify *what* to tag, it tags the current commit, whatever commit HEAD is currently pointing to.

Then, when you do this:

```
git push --tags
```

and git responds with:

```
 * [new tag]         v1.1.0 -> v1.1.0
```

It basically says this:

```
 * [new tag]         v1.1.0 -> v1.1.0
   ^---+---^         ^--+-^    ^--+-^
       |                |         |
       |                |         +-- this is what the tag is now named on the server
       |                +-- this is what your tag is named locally (the one you made)
       +-- this is the server telling you that you gave it a new tag
```

So there is nothing wrong here. You created a new tag. You pushed your new, local, tag to the server, which responded by saying "You gave me a new tag".

---

In your comment you say "Composer won't update the package", which sounds to me like you're using those tags to label your software as well. That's OK, but it's not a **git** problem if those versions are out of sync with your git repository. If the package, that you now upped to v1.1.0, doesn't update in some software, you should check the reference in that software. Perhaps it is restricted in which version it can use? Did you publish your package correctly?

Comment: OK I'm an idiot. I didn't actually PUSH by code, it was still at commit stage. Derp. Really nice answer, thanks